# Need all rows from one table but only selected rows from another

Tags: php, mysql

Using the following:

```
$result223 = mysql_query ("SELECT branches.branch_name, branches.bid as branchid,branch.bid, branch.cid  FROM branches INNER JOIN branch ON branches.bid 
=    branch.bid  group by branchid") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row223 = mysql_fetch_array( $result223 )) {
$x223=$row223['branch_name'];
$x223a=$row223['branchid'];
$x223b=$row223['cid'];
$x223c=$row223['bid'];
echo"<input type='checkbox'name='branch[]value=$x223a'";if($x223b==$var){echo"checked";}echo"> $x223<br>";if($var===$x223b){echo"$x223";}
}
```

$var is a variable to match the cid column. I Get A Checkbox For Each Branch But The cid column is limited to the first 6 rows.

If I use something like:

```
$result333 = mysql_query ("select branch.bid as branchid, branch.cid,branches.bid as brand, branches.branch_name from branch, branches where  
cid=$var and     branches.bid between 1 and 6") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo"<br><br><table border='2px'>";
while($row333 = mysql_fetch_array( $result333 )) {
$x333=$row333['branch_name'];
$x333a=$row333['branchid'];
$x333b=$row333['cid'];
$x333c=$row333['brand'];
echo"<tr><td>";
echo"<input type='checkbox'name='branch[]value=$x333c'";if($x333a==$var){echo"checked";}echo"> $x333<br>";
}
```

I get a double set of rows, all checked. I probably would've figured out how to get rid of the double rows but with what entries there are I should have only had two of them checked. I've been a week in forums, trying so many combos of select queries I figure I should've got things squared away by now but so far a no-go.
I hope I was clear enough on explaining the situation. If it has been covered in a post already, a link to it would be golden.
}

Comment: Can we see the structure of these tables? it doesn't look like there's any real direct relationship being established and it may be better if you just do a `UNION` statement with a nested `SELECT` to get the data you want returned. Thanks.

Comment: Tables are as follows:

Comment: Where is $var declared from the code? I find this `name='branch[]value=$x223a'"` part problematic because it should be `name='branch[]' value ='$x223a'"`, shouldn't it?.  I also wanna comment on your variable names. Those are bad practice of naming variables because of its readability. It would be hard for you to debug later.

Comment: `if($x333a==$var)` this line is wrong because `$x333a` is actually  `$x333a=$row333['branchid']` and what you really want to find is the matching of column cid. The cid column is assigned to this `$x333b=$row333['cid']` variable. The naming is really messed up here.

Comment: $var is, as you detected what should match up with cid. Sorry about the other one also, on the $x233a and b being out of place, it probably ended up like that looking for anything under the sun to try.  As far as the quotes, I fixed them and didn't seem to change anything-must have been to many hours trying to figure this out. Thank you for your reply though--much appreciated.

Comment: The $var variable was just a name for the occasion but represents a user input to match up with cid